# syntax error in compile cool project

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, makefile, mingw

i get project from 
https://github.com/cchuahuico/COOL-Compiler

when compile this code:

```
class Main inherits SuperClass {
  main(): Object {{
    out_string("Enter an integer greater-than or equal-to 0: ");

    let input: Int  in
      if input < 0 then
            input
 --     out_string("ERROR: Number must be greater-than or equal-to 0\n")
      else {
 --       out_string("The factorial of ").out_int(input);
 --       out_string(" is ").out_int(factorial(input));
            factorial(input);
      }
      fi;
  }};

  factorial(num: Int): Int {
    if num = 0 then 1 else num * factorial(num - 1) fi
  };
};

class SuperClass {
out_string(str:String){};
};
```

when compile this with mingw i have this error

```
<stdin>:2:error:syntax error near or aat character or token '{'
<stdin>:5:error:syntax error near or aat character or token 'let'
<stdin>:14:error:syntax error near or aat character or token 'fi'
<stdin>:15:error:syntax error near or aat character or token '}'
<stdin>:23:error:syntax error near or aat character or token '('
<stdin>:24:error:syntax error near or aat character or token '}'
<stdin>:24:error:syntax error near or aat character or token ' '
copmilation halted due to lexical or syntax errors
```

Comment: this project is cool compiler

Comment: You need to use the COOL compiler, not mingw.  If mingw supports COOL, you will need to configure the compiler.  According to the info, this language is used for learning how to create compilers.

Comment: It appears that you are trying to compile a Cool example with mingw. 
You can't compile Cool code with mingw: it is a compiler for C and C++. The Cool compiler is a program written in C++, so you compile the Cool compiler with mingw. When you have built the Cool compiler, then you can compile Cool code with *it*.

Answer (score 1):

The mingw compiler is complaining because the language is not standard C++:

1. The `inherits` keyword.      Although, it could be `#define` as
   anything.
2. `fi` is not a keyword.
3. The `if` statement needs `parens` `()` around the expression.
4. `let` is not a keyword.
5. `then` is not a keyword.

// There are a lot more

Is this another language?

Comment: tnx. yes this is a cool language and my project is cool compiler